# Apache, Invalid LoadModule mod_auth_basic

Tags: apache, xampp

I have encountered a problem where apache does not start.

As for my investigation I went to `Control Panel/Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application`

and found out this error

`httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 79 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid LoadModule path modules/mod_auth_basic.so`

Running `apache_start.bat` would also give me the same error. How do you fix this error?

Comment: Is there a directory `modules`?  Is `mod_auth_basic.so` in there?

Comment: I noticed that the module file has been corrupted. The heck it did get corrupted and that it only affected 1 file. One Specific File!